# cannot view partition through nautilus

Tags: linux, permissions, partitioning, mount, nautilus

I'm trying to view access files from another partition on my fedora 17 box, but it says "The folder contents could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "alex"".

I'm running nautilus on Fedora 17 in an account with the same user name and password that owns the files from the other partition, which probably doesn't mean anything. How would I give myself permission to view my own files on the other partition?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

Files are stored on your file system and are pointed to by inodes. Inodes contain file metadata such as access controls, creation/modification/access time, and its user ID.

When you list files with commands like `ls` or `stat`, they map the UID to a username using /etc/passwd as the key. You can tell them to not resolve UID->username by `ls -n $file` or `stat -c %u $file`.

If you type `id`, you'll see the current UID under which you're operating. If the UID of the files on the other partition is different than your current UID, you'll see this problem. If you have root access, you can change the ownership of the files to be your regular user's UID (`man chown`), the UID located in your current operating system's /etc/passwd file. Then you should be able to access the files as your regular user.

That is, if your problem is a UID mismatch :)

Comment: Hello Sean, thanks for the explanation. So if if I mount the partition then do chown on everything, I should be able to view the files through nautilus? Would I still be able to log into the system on the other partition if the ownership of the files is changed?

Comment: I don't see a reason not to make the UIDs identical in each system's /etc/passwd.

Note that when you do this, all files will be shown to be owned by an unknown UID number since the UID->mapping can no longer be made. You'll have to go through the entire filesystem and `chown` all the files owned by the old UID and make them owned by the new UID. You can probably most easily do this with the `find` command along with the -exec option.